# Magento Store URL

Tags: magento

Something bizarre happened a few days ago. Been working on a Magento CE 1.8.1 site and the URLs used to be https://www.yourdomainname.com/category-name.html

Now it has been updated to https://www.yourdomainname.com/default/category-name.html and I don't know how to remove /default from the URL.

Has anyone came across such an issue? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if 'Add store code to URL is set to 'No'?

The option is located under Web -> URL Options. It only appears when you have 'Default config' set as configuration scope.